# J meter - Mobile app recording - SSL HandshakeException

Tags: performance, jmeter, load

I am getting below responce in result tree when record mobile app using j meter javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown

Answer (score 1):

You need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate onto your "mobile" device, the file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it's generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

Once done depending on your "mobile" operating system:

- iOS: [enable full trust for root certificates](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT204477)

  [image]
- Android: [amend network_security_config.xml file](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices) like this:

  ```
   <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <trust-anchors>
           <certificates src="system" />
           <certificates src="user" />
       </trust-anchors> 
   </base-config>
  ```

  then re-build your "mobile app" in debug mode and replace the version installed on the device